# Pass data between html pages using angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to pass form data between html pages without using services.

Here is my code link --> http://plnkr.co/edit/E6LM5Oq67XRcvVuMIv9i?p=preview
Below is my contacts.html page.

```
 <html>
<head>
<title>Contacts Page</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular-route.js"></script>
 <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" >
<table>
<tr>
<th>User ID</th>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Phone Number</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
<td>{{contact.uid}}</td>
<td>{{contact.fname}}</td>
<td>{{contact.lname}}</td>
<td>{{contact.pphone}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The data is not getting passed to contacts.html.How to do this ?

Comment: Please include all relevant information (including code) in your question. Have a look at [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Both are different HTML pages. You can't pass data like that.

Comment: I am able to display the data in the same html page,but any other way to display data in another ?

Comment: You can pass the data over to a different page as query string parameters

Comment: you seem to be missing some of the point of how Single Page Application frameworks like angular operate;  SPAs, and in particular angular, are designed to not have your app across multiple HTML pages.

Comment: Angular is for SPA. So, you should use routing concept to achieve this.

Answer (score -2):

Using rootScope we can archive this.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.carname = "Volvo";
    $rootScope.car=$scope.carname;
});
app.controller('controllerTwo', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.getcarname = $rootScope.car;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<h1>{{carname}}</h1>



<div ng-controller="controllerTwo">

<h1>Using rootscope: {{getcarname}}</h1>

</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: this isn't the intended purpose of `$rootScope`;  while this *might* work, it's not a good idea to teach bad practices like this.

Comment: also, this won't work in the case of this problem anyway, since even `$rootScope` only works within a single angular app, and the example here has two separate HTML pages, with a unique angular app on each.